# NHibernate+Oracle: How to avoid millisecond truncation on insert

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, oracleclient

Mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="OracleHibernateTest" namespace="OracleHibernateTest">
<class name="TableRow" table="TIMESTAMP_TEST_2">
    <id name="Id" />
    <property name="Time" type="Timestamp">
        <column name="TIME" sql-type="TIMESTAMP(4)"></column>
    </property>    
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Code:

```
    var configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.Configure();
    var export = new SchemaExport(configuration);
    export.Create((s) => Trace.WriteLine(s), true);
    var sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
    using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        var testItem = new TableRow() { Id = (new Random().Next()), Time = new DateTime(2014, 8, 25, 5, 12, 4, 587) };
        session.Save(testItem);
        session.Flush();
    }
```

Code above will insert new row, but milliseconds in Time column are truncated.

From investigation I have found that NHibernate will create OracleParameter for SQL command with parameter where OracleType is set to DateTime instead of TimeStamp.
In Oracle DateTime have no milliseconds.

Comment: Something is wrong - somewhere else. The example you gave will ALWAYS issue statement with **milliseconds**. Your mapping and code is correct. Check with some profiler what is passed to DB, I'd say...

Answer (score 0):

After more investigation I tried to update Oracle client drivers (ODAC 12c Release 2 12.1.0.1.2 Xcopy) to latest version available and that solved my problem. Seems like issue with older Oracle drivers.